# Pointer changes value without reason?

Tags: c, pointers, yacc

I have to do this project on Flex/Yacc, where I must calculate the Abstract Syntax Tree of an Insiemistic expression. But the real problem is within the C code.

I've made this function, that creates a node:

```
node_t * createNode(node_content_t nodecontent, int nodetype){
    node_t *newNode = (node_t *) malloc(sizeof(node_t * ));
    if(nodetype == 0){
        newNode->content = (node_content_t)strdup(nodecontent.string);
    }
    else
        newNode->content = nodecontent;
    newNode->type = nodetype;

    newNode->leftChild = NULL;
    newNode->rightChild = NULL;
    printf("Right Child in createNode: %p\n", newNode->rightChild);
    return newNode;
}
```

As you can see, left and right child are both initialized to null. But when i try to print the pointer value of the right child out of the function, it changes value(tipically to 0x23 or 0x53), leading to a segmentation fault.

node_t and node_content_t are defined as follows

```
typedef union{
        char* string;
        char singleletter;
    }node_content_t;


    typedef struct node node_t;
    struct node{
        node_content_t content;
        int type; //0 for string, 1 for char
        node_t *leftChild;
        node_t *rightChild;
    };
```

When i tried to print the pointer in `createNode`, it resulted 0x0, i printed it in this function printNode, that should print the entire tree:

```
void printNode(node_t *n, size_t indent) {
    
    char *indentation = malloc(sizeof(char) * indent);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < indent; ++i) {
        indentation[i] = ' ';
    }
    printf("LeftChild: %p\n", n->leftChild);
    printf("RightChild: %p\n", n->rightChild);
    switch (n->type) {
        case 0: printf("%s%s\n", indentation, n->content); break;
        case 1: printf("%s%c\n", indentation, n->content); break;
    }
    if (n->leftChild != NULL){
        printNode(n->leftChild, indent+2);
    }
    if (n->rightChild != NULL){
        printf("RightChild: %p\n", n->rightChild); //there
        printNode(n->rightChild, indent+2);
    }
    printf("Non ci sono figli\n");

}
```

And as i said, the value change, so the function doesn't work, any ideas? I don't modify the value of rightChild if not in the function addChild:

```
void addChild(node_t *parent, node_t *child) {
    printf("Addchild\n");
    printf("Right Child in createNode: %p\n", parent->rightChild);
    if(parent->leftChild == NULL)
        parent->leftChild = child;
    else if(parent->rightChild == NULL && strcmp(parent->content.string, "co") != 0 ){
        parent-> rightChild = child;
        printf("Aggiunto figlio destro\nContent: %c\nType: %d\n", child->content, child->type);
    }
    else
        printf("Error during child adding\n");
}
```

Comment: `node_t *newNode = (node_t *) malloc(sizeof(node_t * ));` only allocates the size of a pointer, not your node structure... Better: `node_t *newNode = malloc(sizeof *newNode );`

Comment: `indentation` is NOT a null terminated string. Don't use it with `%s` in `printf()`...

Comment: The malloc solution worked, i'm kind of rusty in C programmation, it's easy to see. Thanks btw :)

Comment: The code shown does not `free( indentation );`. Memory leaking... Easier to skip the allocation and simply loop on `putchar( ' ' );` counting up to `indent`...

Comment: @iLux24 You can consider posting an answer and mark it as solved.

Comment: @Zakk i posted the answer to the problem, i have to wait two days for marking it as solution. If someone wants to write another response, i'm happy to mark that as solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem 1:**

```
node_t *newNode = (node_t *) malloc(sizeof(node_t * ));
```

1. This allocates enough space for `node_t *`; not the `node_t` struct you intend.
2. Casting is unnecessary (and could be harmful.)
3. Better to use the variable's *name* rather than its *type* (reducing future maintenance.)
4. `malloc()` can fail. Get used to checking return values. Make it a habit!

```
node_t *newNode = malloc( sizeof *newNode ); // cleaner
if( newNode == NULL ) { /* handle error condition */ }
```

**Problem 2:**

```
void printNode(node_t *n, size_t indent) {
    
    char *indentation = malloc(sizeof(char) * indent); // <== never free'd
    for (size_t i = 0; i < indent; ++i) { // unnecessary...
        indentation[i] = ' ';
    }
    printf("LeftChild: %p\n", n->leftChild);
    printf("RightChild: %p\n", n->rightChild);
    switch (n->type) {
        case 0: printf("%s%s\n", indentation, n->content); break;
        case 1: printf("%s%c\n", indentation, n->content); break;
    }
```

5. `indentation` is allocated each time this function is called, and it is never `free()`'d.
   Memory leak (hastening the occurrence of allocation failing.)
6. `indentation` is NOT *null terminated* and must not be treated as a C string.

Get rid of the lines performing the allocation and utilise the capabilities of `printf()`. Eg:

```
printf( "%*s%s\n", indent, "", n->content ); break;
```

`%*s` gets the *field width specifier* from the next parameter, in this case `indent`. It then gets the string to be printed in a field that wide, in this case `""`. The result is a *prefix* of the desired number of spaces on each line.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in the `malloc()` call: `node_t *newNode = (node_t *) malloc(sizeof(node_t * ));` only allocates the size of a pointer.

To solve, change it to `node_t *newNode = malloc(sizeof *newNode);`.